# java-contains but with specific parameters

Tags: java, collections, contains

I have a question about "contains" method in java. 
I have the object Tile, that includes int x, int y (coordinates), and string.
I want to add objects to a queue, without duplicates.
when I say duplicates, I mean to the coordinates. I don't care about the string.

but when I write something like this:

```
for (Tile x : neighbours)
{
    if (!queue.contains(x))
        queue.add(x);
}
```

it's add all, and my guess is that he sees that one parameter isn't equal (the string) 
and because of that he put x in the queue.

Do you know how am I put new objects in the queue only according to the coordinates?
two objects with the same coordinates but with a different string, is the same object for me.

thanks...

Comment: What is the type of `queue`?

Comment: How is `Tile`'s `equals` method impemented?

Answer (score 0):

To check for an element that matches a property, without being equal, it may be simplest to use a loop. However, if you want to use a single method, you can pass a lambda as a predicate to `anyMatch`:

```
for (Tile x : neighbours) {
    if (!queue.stream().anyMatch(t -> x.x == t.x && x.y == t.y)) {
        queue.add(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i already did this function. i though there is a short "magic".

```
public static boolean containsCoordinates (LinkedList<Tile> queue, Tile obj)
{
    for (Tile queueTile : queue)
    {
         if (queueTile.getX()==obj.getX())
         {
             if (queueTile.getY()==obj.getY())
                 return true;
         }
    }

    return false;
}
```

thanks anyway....

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use some "magic", then you could consider the following test:

```
for (Tile x : neighbours) {
    if (!queue.contains(new Object() {
        public boolean equals(Object t) {
            return x.x == ((Tile) t).x && x.y == ((Tile) t).y;
        }
    })) {
        queue.add(x);
    }
}
```

where I do not pass the given Tile `t` to the `contains` method but rather an `Object` instance with an overridden `equals` method. This works, as `contains` accepts objects of any type.

From the program logic however this version is equivalent to the answer given by @Joe

Answer (score -1):

From documentation of [java.util.Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) (which defines the `contains` method and which is a superinterface of Queue):

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

So override the `equals` method of the `Title` to fit your needs. E.g.

```java
class Tile {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Title)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        return this.x == o.x && this.y == o.y;
    }
    ...
}
```

IDEs such as Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea are able to generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods (when you override one, you should always override the other too).

Comment: i already did this function. i though there is a short "magic".                                                             public static boolean containsCoordinates (LinkedList<Tile> queue, Tile obj)
 {
  for (Tile queueTile : queue)
  {
    if (queueTile.getX()==obj.getX())
    {
     if (queueTile.getY()==obj.getY())
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
 }                                                  thanks anyway....